# Remove vertical white space between images of same width in a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

My gallery looks like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBGhbPaJU_jdUl3cGdNQjVNVjg

As you can see that's my gallery, I would like the spaces below and between the images gone. (Indicated by the arrows)

Here is my code:

```css
/*Gallery*/
#works-gallery{
 margin:0px;
 position:relative;
 top:900px;
 width:1440;
 text-align:center;
 line-height: 0;
 column-count: auto;
 column-gap:0px;
 -webkit-column-count:auto;
 -webkit-column-gap:0px;
 -moz-column-count:auto;
 -moz-column-gap:0px;
}

#works-gallery img {
 postion:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 width:480px;
 height:auto;
 top:0px;
 vertical-align:top;
 padding:0px;
 border:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="works-gallery">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/320/abstract" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/456/city" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/456/city" class="tile" />
    
    <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/234/fashion" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/567/food" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/356/nature" class="tile" />
        
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/678/nightlife" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/243/people" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/678/sports" class="tile" />
        
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/256/technics" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/678/transport" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/235/abstract" class="tile" />
        
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/678/animals" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/657/city" class="tile" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/789/fashion" class="tile" />

</div>
```

What do I have to change please?

Comment: That's because your images have different aspect ratios. Are you willing to stretch those landscape photos to fit with your portrait photos?

Comment: If you want  to have elements of different size, you will have to move each manually with position.

Comment: @JkAlombro No, I want to keep the aspect ratios as original

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the vertical align attribute

Comment: Where should I move it to?